# passing va_list around results in invalid data

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I've found several questions on this but none of them have helped me get this working.
I have the following.

```
struct general_calibration_t {
    double pressure_span;
    double pressure_offset;
    double steam_temperature_offset;
};

struct general_t {
    struct general_calibration_t calibration;
};

int generateGenericJSON(string* str, const char* json, ...) {
    char* tmp = (char*)malloc(2048);
    if (tmp == NULL)
        goto fail;

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, json);
    const int amount = snprintf(tmp, 2048, json, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (amount >= 2048 || amount < 0)
        goto release;

    string_new_value(str, tmp, amount);
    free(tmp);
    return 0;

release:
    free(tmp);
fail:
    return 1;
}
```

Which is called with the following:

```
    struct general_t data;
    data.calibration.pressure_offset = 1.0;
    data.calibration.pressure_span = 34.8;
    data.calibration.steam_temperature_offset = 20.0;
    string calibrationStr;
    generateGenericJSON(&calibrationStr, 
        "\"Calibration\":{\"PressureSpan\":%.3f,\"PressureOffset\":%.3f,\"SteamTemperatureOffset\":%.3f}", 
        data.calibration.pressure_span, 
        data.calibration.pressure_offset, 
        data.calibration.steam_temperature_offset);
```

My output is the following:

```
"Calibration":{"PressureSpan":0.000,"PressureOffset":0.000,"SteamTemperatureOffset":-92559631349317830736831783200707727132248687965119994463780864.000}
```

Something appears wrong while passing the `va_list` to `snprintf`. If I use `va_arg` to walk through the list in the function `generateGenericJSON` the data is correct. I tried passing the `va_list` as a pointer but I get the same invalid data. 
What am I doing wrong in passing this `va_list` to `snprintf`?

Comment: @dash-o This is definitely an appropriate use of `goto`.

Comment: @dash-o This is very common in kernel, driver, and rtos code. A quick grep over the Linux kernel shows its used 155488 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What am I doing wrong in passing this va_list to snprintf?*

You want to use [`vsnprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) instead of `snprintf()`.

---

Following up *dash-o*'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58891633/passing-va-list-around-results-in-invalid-data#comment104048884_58891633): Try to avoid (the possibility of) spagetti-code.

A possible way to handle the different cases of success/failure could be:

```
int generateGenericJSON(string* str, const char* json, ...) {
  int result = 0; /* Be optimistic. */

  do { /* One time "loop" */
    char* tmp = malloc(2048); /* No need to cast malloc() and friends in C. */
    if (tmp == NULL) {
      result = -1; /* By convention -1 indicates failure. */
      break;
    }

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, json);
    const int amount = vsnprintf(tmp, 2048, json, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    if (amount >= 2048 || amount < 0) {
      result = -1;
      break;
    }

    string_new_value(str, tmp, amount);
  } while (0);

  free(tmp); /* Passing NULL to free is fine. */

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely an appropriate use of `goto`. I don't see why it wouldn't be. And I don't see why you need the `do { ... } while(0);`.

Comment: My comment was related to `tmp = malloc(...) ; if ( !tmp) goto err ; ... ; err: return 1`. No reason not to write `tmp = malloc(...) ; if ( !tmp ) return 1`. I do not see the value o the goto.

Comment: I feel following the pattern of having one exit point per function only is a good idea.